# Windows 7 taskbar: don't highlight quick launch buttons when program is run

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When quick launch (QL) items are run, these QL buttons are shown as pressed, to indicate that the program is run. So I can't run program again (2nd instance) using QL. How to use old WinXP behaviour, when QL buttons are not drawn as pressed (and new taskbar buttons, on right side, 're created for running programs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 there is no more Quick Launch by default, just shortcut icons `pinned` to the Taskbar.

If you need to open another instance of a running program from the Taskbar, right-click the icon and choose the program name again.

[image]

You also may want to check into the "Taskbar buttons:" option in the Taskbar's properties.  Specifically "Never combine" to keep them from stacking.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a an article describing how to enable quick launch in Windows 7:

"Guided Help: Enable the Quick Launch bar in Windows 7" - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975784

> By default, the Quick Launch bar is not available in Windows 7. To open programs quickly, you can drag the program icons to the taskbar.
>
> However, you can follow the steps in this article to restore the Quick Launch bar and the Show Desktop button as it was in Microsoft Windows Vista and Windows XP.